# Angular Formly - Template - Wrapping LABEL in its own class

Tags: angular-formly

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for presentation. The design calls for labels and input fields to be on the same line for desktop and stacked for mobile. To achieve this I would like to use TB's grid system but I can't find a way to do this. Looking through the documentation I can see how to apply a class to the wrapper div for a label/input pair but not to the label and input fields individually.

http://jsbin.com/voreyev/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the standard bootstrap grid system to achieve this. E.g.

```
<label class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">name</label>

<input type="text" class="col-sm-12 col-md-8" />
```

This will use the media queries built into bootstrap to force the label onto its own line on small screens and inline on larger screens.

Comment: Yep I get that. But I don't know how to achieve this with formly as templates are configured from JS and there isn't an obvious way of applying a class to the label.